# CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm currently facing some issues with creation of `CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")` object.

```
Public Function PrepareHttpRequest(Request As RestRequest, TimeoutMS As Long, _
Optional UseAsync As Boolean = False) As Object
Dim Http As Object
**Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")**

' Set timeouts
Http.setTimeouts TimeoutMS, TimeoutMS, TimeoutMS, TimeoutMS

' Add general headers to request
Request.AddHeader "User-Agent", UserAgent
Request.AddHeader "Content-Type", Request.ContentType

If Request.IncludeContentLength Then
    Request.AddHeader "Content-Length", Request.ContentLength
Else
    If Request.Headers.Exists("Content-Length") Then
        Request.Headers.Remove "Content-Length"
    End If
End If

' Pass http to request and setup onreadystatechange
If UseAsync Then
    Set Request.HttpRequest = Http
    Http.onreadystatechange = Request
End If

Set PrepareHttpRequest = Http
End Function
```

The above code is working fine for some users but its failing in some users machine. Can anyone please provide necessary changes to fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

Otherwise put an `On Error Goto ln` and tell us what the `Err.Description` is and google it

Run ProcessMonitor to see where its trying to find the DLL and regsvr32 the msxml6.dll